# Tailwind Flowbite modal not working with animation

Tags: modal-dialog, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, flowbite

I'm new in Tailwind CSS, and I'm using Flowbite as a ready made components via CDN. However, many options don't work with animation.  Like that, modal is one of them. All the modal always open with a zoom in out effect, but in this case modal open directly, no animation working.

Here's my code:

```
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/1.6.4/flowbite.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/1.6.4/flowbite.min.js'></script>



<!-- Modal toggle -->
<button data-modal-target="defaultModal" data-modal-toggle="defaultModal" class="block text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800" type="button">
  Toggle modal
</button>

<!-- Main modal -->
<div id="defaultModal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" class="fixed top-0 left-0 right-0 z-50 hidden w-full p-4 overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto md:inset-0 h-[calc(100%-1rem)] max-h-full">
    <div class="relative w-full max-w-2xl max-h-full">
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-700">
            <!-- Modal header -->
            <div class="flex items-start justify-between p-4 border-b rounded-t dark:border-gray-600">
                <h3 class="text-xl font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
                    Terms of Service
                </h3>
                <button type="button" class="text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5 ml-auto inline-flex items-center dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white" data-modal-hide="defaultModal">
                    <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close modal</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="p-6 space-y-6">
                <p class="text-base leading-relaxed text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                    With less than a month to go before the European Union enacts new consumer privacy laws for its citizens, companies around the world are updating their terms of service agreements to comply.
                </p>
                <p class="text-base leading-relaxed text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                    The European Union’s General Data Protection Regulation (G.D.P.R.) goes into effect on May 25 and is meant to ensure a common set of data rights in the European Union. It requires organizations to notify users as soon as possible of high-risk data breaches that could personally affect them.
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="flex items-center p-6 space-x-2 border-t border-gray-200 rounded-b dark:border-gray-600">
                <button data-modal-hide="defaultModal" type="button" class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">I accept</button>
                <button data-modal-hide="defaultModal" type="button" class="text-gray-500 bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 rounded-lg border border-gray-200 text-sm font-medium px-5 py-2.5 hover:text-gray-900 focus:z-10 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300 dark:border-gray-500 dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:focus:ring-gray-600">Decline</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I fix it ?